# How can I prevent an image inside a flex container from growing taller than the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a lightbox-like situation in which an image and various accessory UI are inside a container with a specified height, and they don't grow beyond that height. The image should be "contained" (you should be able to see the whole thing) and it should be as wide and tall as possible without forcing themselves or their sibling elements to grow beyond the container.

I thought this would be easy to do well with flexbox, but I'm having a tougher time than expected.

Here is a [codepen of my attempt](https://codepen.io/tboutell/pen/LYJqPEV), and here is the source for convenience:

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/2000">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  img {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
</style>
```

Note that even though the `box` div has a height of `100vh`, the image winds up at a width of `100%` and proportionally a height much taller than `100vh`. If I were to set it to exactly `100vh`, it would obey that, but the rest of the UI would still be forced below the configured height of the flex parent. I only want the image to grow into available space within the configured height of the parent.

Thanks.

Comment: use `max-width: 100%` on the image.

Comment: @tacoshy that change has no effect. The width is already respecting the container. The height however is not (and if the height did respect the container, it would also need to shrink the width so that the image remains proportional).

Comment: sorry I misread. You can add the same for the height as long the height is defined as well.

Comment: min-height: 0 to the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif would you like to submit that as an answer? It works, and it's a one-line change. Thanks!

Comment: It also continues to work when the parent is narrow as opposed to wide.